# A point in a circle is selected at random. Calculate probability that point is closer to centre than circumference

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-theory, conditional-probability

State any assumption(s) you make

Well, I decided to draw a circle with a center at the origin of a Cartesian plane. It had radius r so it's coordinates on the axes were (0, r), etc.

I then drew another circle inside with half the radius so (0, 1/2r), etc.

So every point needs to be inside the center but not on it and I wasn't given particular values. How should I go about doing this further?

Comment: How much area does the inside circle have relative to the big circle? How does that relate to the probability of landing in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** What about take the ratio $$\frac{\text{Area of the small circle}}{\text{Area of the big circle}}=\frac{\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}r^2\right)}{\pi r^2}=\frac{1}{4}?$$

Comment: yeah. That makes sense but what about the points on the smaller circle. Are they supposed to be included. Because those are equal distance right

Comment: oh. How about area of a circle with (r-1)

Comment: The area of the points on the inner circle is 0, so it doesn't matter which way you count them.

Comment: No but if it is at 1/2 r then it is equally distant from the origin as it is from the circumference

Comment: Right but that will happen (landing on the inner circle) with probability 0.